# how to improve performance when group by columns are from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose there is a sql

```
select
    t_1.a,
    t_2.c,
    min(t_2.d)
from t_1
join t_2 on t1.b = t2.b
group by t1.a, t2.c
```

The schema is as below

```
 CREATE TABLE `t_1` (
`a` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `b` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `idx_a_b` (`a`,`b`),
  KEY `idx_a` (`a`),
  KEY `idx_b` (`b`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `t_2` (
  `b` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `c` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `d` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `b` (`b`,`c`),
  KEY `idx_c` (`c`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The explain shows as below

1   SIMPLE  t_2 ALL b   NULL    NULL    NULL    285480  Using temporary; Using filesort

1   SIMPLE  t_1 ref idx_b   idx_b   8   t_2.b   11

Comment: It wouldn't matter as when group by is run the resultset is in-memory. Before running group by it will run the join and pull the matching records then it will run group by. So columns from both the tables would be in the memory.

Comment: Are there indices on the columns used for "group by" and "join"?

Comment: Typically, questions about query performance require CREATE TABLE statements for relevant tables, and the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the create table and explain